# Why this mov gs instruction causes a fault in VMWare Workstation guest running Windows 7 OS?

Tags: assembly, kernel, vmware, virtualization, windows-kernel

When I run the following assembly sequence in a kernel mode of Windows 7 x64 running in a VMWare Workstation virtual machine:

```
xor eax, eax
mov ax, gs
mov gs, ax     ; this instruction
```

[image]

that last `mov gs, ax` instruction immediately causes that VM to crash (or possibly bug-check) with the following pop-up message:

[image]

> A fault has occurred causing a virtual CPU to enter the shutdown
>   state. If this fault had occurred outside of a virtual machine, it
>   would have caused the physical machine to restart. The shutdown state
>   can be reached by incorrectly configuring the virtual machine, a bug
>   in the guest operating system, or a problem in VMWare Workstation.

Does re-loading `gs` register as such cause the issue in the kernel, or is it a virtualization issue?

I don't see anything unusual about that `mov` instruction in the Intel manual.

PS. By the way, replacing `gs` register with `fs` does not cause this fault.

---

**Edit:** To answer the question about the state of the segment descriptor in GDT. Here it is:

```
0: kd> r gs
gs=002b
0: kd> dg 28
                                                    P Si Gr Pr Lo
Sel        Base              Limit          Type    l ze an es ng Flags
---- ----------------- ----------------- ---------- - -- -- -- -- --------
0028 00000000`00000000 00000000`ffffffff Data RW Ac 3 Bg Pg P  Nl 00000cf3
```

Comment: You can move a segment register directly to a 32-bit register. No need to zero eax and then you can just do `mov eax, gs` `mov gs, eax` . I assume you are doing this as en experiment. When you load a segment register even if it was the same as the previous value it will reload from the GDT. If somehow the descriptor in the GDT is now invalid it could throw an exception when loaded into GS.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Oh, heck I can do the whole `mov rax, gs` instead. That was the goal. Thanks. It just zero-extends it. Cool! And yes, I was running my experiments on it. As for your second point, then no, the GDT is untouched, as-is in the 64-bit kernel. It's just that little assembly sequence that causes this issue in a VM. That's why I'm asking here. Is it a bug/feature in the VM or something in the kernel, or maybe Intel does some behind-the-scenes stuff when `gs` is loaded. I'm trying to learn....

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Updated my answer. PS. I thought Windows didn't use LDTs. It's just a flat read/write data segment as it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why the move `mov gs,ax` would cause Windows to immediately triple fault, but it would soon enough cause it to crash.  In the 64-bit Windows kernel the GS segment is used as a pointer to access the current CPU's [Processor Control Region](https://www.andrea-allievi.com/blog/x64-memory-segmentation-is-the-game-over/) (PCR). Each CPU has a different GS base value pointing to a different PCR. Your `mov ax,gs` `mov gs,ax` sequence actually breaks this because it loads an incorrect value for the GS base into the descriptor cache.

The GDT doesn't actually contain the correct base for the GS register. Since the GDT can only hold 32-bit addresses, it's not actually used to load the GS base. Instead the IA32_GS_BASE and IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE MSRs, the later in combination with the SWAPGS instruction, are used to set a 64-bit base address for the GS segment. The selector value stored in the GS register is just a dummy value.

So your `mov gs,ax` instruction loads the dummy 32-bit base value stored in the GDT, not the 64-bit value stored in IA32_GS_BASE. This means that the base address of the GS segment is set to 0 and not to the address of the PCR for the current CPU.  After loading this incorrect GS base it's only a matter of time before the Windows kernel tries to use the GS register to access the PCR (with an instruction like `mov rax, gs:[10]`) and ends up reading what is probably unmapped memory causing an unexpected kernel page fault and crashing.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks. It actually crashes as soon as I try to step over that `mov gs, ax` instruction with WinDbg. It never returns "to the other side of that instruction" so-to-speak, and the VM shows the error message I displayed above. So interesting. I didn't know that GDT wasn't actually used to read the base and limit for the segment. But if so, at what point are IA32_GS_BASE and IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE msrs set? I'm somewhat confused about that.

Comment: @c00000fd The IA32_GS_BASE and the IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE Model Specific Registers (MSRs) are set in the routine KiSystemStartup (an undocumented routine of NTOSKRNL) - this routine is the "entry-point" to NTOSKRNL. Setting the MSRs is achieved via the `wrmsr` instruction (https://imgur.com/vCkFqNl).

Comment: @c00000fd My guess is that the debugging stub in the Windows kernel that's crashing, since it or and device driver it uses may need access to the PCR. Not sure why this would cause a triple fault though. Maybe because nested faults end being generated endlessly until the stack fills and causes a double fault then a triple fault.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR: Thanks. So the base address that is present in GDT is not used in 64-bit mode at all, right? I'm assuming the limit is not either, hah?

Comment: @RossRidge: Yeah, probably. Although what happens behind the scenes when `mov gs, ax` is called? I'm still not clear about it. There's nothing changed. I'm just reloading the same value back into it. Btw, just from curiosity, how do you know that it's causing a triple fault?

Comment: @c00000fd The base address in the GDT isn't used by Windows but it's used by the CPU when you load the descriptor into the GS (or FS) register. That's what causes the problem, the base address in the GDT (00000000) is incorrect, and not the value the base address of the GS segment had before. You've reloaded the GS register with the same value, but this doesn't reload GS.base with the same value. The limit and attributes are in the GDT are ignored by the CPU. I know it's a triple fault because they cause the CPU to enter a shutdown sate.

Comment: @RossRidge: Oh, OK. I see now. So when I call `mov gs, ax` the base addr is reset to 0 when it's supposed to be something else. Oh, and `SWAPGS` instruction can load the base addr all by itself. And that's what they use in the kernel during `syscall`/`sysret`. Did I get it right? It starts to make sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @c00000fd The SWAPGS instruction swaps the values of GS.base and IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE MSR. The GS.base value can also be read and written to using the IA32_GS_BASE MSR so this also has the effect of swapping these two MSRs. The SWAPGS instruction is used to set GS to point to PCR on entry to the kernel and to set the GS to point to the 64-bit TIB/TEB on exit from the kernel.

Comment: @RossRidge: Hah. Interesting. Thanks. I also just noticed that there's no `SWAPFS` instruction although there are MSRs for the FS segment base. All-in-all, it sounds  to me like Intel/AMD were tailor-making their 64-bit architecture for the Windows kernel. (Unless Linux is using that segment register the same way as well.) I also just realized how much CPU architecture has progressed since late 90's when I was learning x86 set. Now just the list of MSRs is totally overwhelming. Anyway. sorry for the rant. Last question. What about segment limits on FS and GS. Are they ignored?

Comment: They're ignored. See the section titled "Segment Loading Instructions in IA-32e Mode" in the Intel SDM Volume 3 System Programming Guide.